# Javascript being ignored in my jsp file implemented in spring mvc

Tags: java, javascript, spring, jsp, jstl

I'm having a login page in a jsp file, which also utilizes jstl, and a simple javascript validation to check whether its fields are empty or not.

On clicking the 'Login' button, its supposed to be checking if the fields are full and then, if true, pass the form details to the Dispatcher Servelet and do the rest of the process.

But on clicking the submit button, the javascript is totally ignored and so if a blank field is there, an exception occurs.
Why is this happening?

This is the code I've used:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
  <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>iLitmus Portal</title>

<link href="<c:url value="resources/css/login.css" />" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="<c:url value="resources/css/common.css" />" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="<c:url value="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amaranth" />"        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="<c:url value="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Convergence" />" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<%@ include file="header.jsp" %> 


</head>
<body >

<div id="portal_banner" align="center">
<img src="resources/images/logo-main.png" id="logo">
<p>Litmus iPortal</p>
</div> 


<div id="loginbox">
<div align="center">
<h3 id="chngpass_title">Login</h3>

<form:form name="frm" method="post" action="login" onsubmit="return validateForm()" commandName="login">
<form:input type="text" path="emp_id" name="username" placeholder="Employee-ID"/><br>
<form:input type="password" path="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password"/>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Login">
<br>
<b> ${error} </b>
<p id="firstuser">If you are a first time user, please login with the predefined  password. You will be directed to change your password and set up
a security question and answer.</p>

</form:form>
</div>
</div>

<script>

function validateForm()
{
if(document.frm.username.value==""&&document.frm.pwd.value!="")
{
  alert("User Name should not be left blank");

  return false;
}
else if(document.frm.pwd.value==""&&document.frm.username.value!="")
{
  alert("Password should not be left blank");

  return false;
}

else if(document.frm.pwd.value==""&&document.frm.username.value==""){

    alert("Username and Password cannot be empty!");
    return false;
}
return true;
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried this initially by placing the javascript code in an external .js file and that did not work so I tried putting it in the jsp page to check if that would work.
I had also tried out a jquery based validation similar to this logic but that also didn't work.

Im doing this in Eclipse Juno with Tomcat server.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: post your script in head section of jsp

Comment: @amitbhardwaj I had tried that too. Did not work :(

Comment: Specify an ID instead of a name. The `name` attributes is used for submitting the form the id for clientside lookups. Also the fact that you do clientside validation doesn't mean you shouldn't do validation on the serverside anymore, never trust your clients so validate on the server always!

Comment: You are using both name and path attributes which is not necessary as path is converted to name and id internally.

Comment: try some alert in your script and check the value you are getting of username and password

Comment: Have you already used the script debugger of your browser. In chrome for example hit ctrl+i to open it. Then place a breakpoint in your javascript and check if it is called. Also you can inspect the real interpreted html state in there, which can differ from the send plain html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code without using the jsp `<form>` tag and it's working fine in this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/go4vaibhav/mqb6jdhz/5/).

Also in order to bind the form to your form bean, you have to use the same name and id attributes for input fields like this,

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Employee-ID"/>
<input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" placeholder="Password"/>
```

Also, using the path and name attributes together while using jsp tags is not a good practice. Put the javascript code in the fiddle in the `<head>` tag.

**UPDATE**

Please use the same name which you used for `path` attribute and the field name in your Servlet class. For instance, if you are giving the `path` attribute as `emp_id` then use the same name in your Servlet. Same for other fields too.

Comment: I'm gonna give this a shot. Can the 'commandName' attribute be replaced with 'name'?

Comment: @Yami sure, let us know if you got any issues trying this.

Comment: The validation worked like a charm so thank you!! But unfortunately, when I clicked on 'Login', a null pointer exception was thrown, ie, the form details did not reach the Dispatcher Servelet.

Comment: I replaced the jsp <form> tag to simply display the validation messages in javascript, so I think there should be no problem using the <form:form name="frm" method="post" action="login" onsubmit="return validateForm()" commandName="login">. This may also be the reason for your exception.

Comment: If I use the jsp <form> tag, then will the path value be taken in document.frm.pathname or will the id value be taken?